# How to use input and printing in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

On my first Objective C project, I am dealing with a code for a general form of the game Mastermind. I currently have a program that allows the computer to generate four out of six random "colors," and I was wondering if anyone can show me how to modify it so a person can type four colors of it's choosing to guess the colors chosen by the computer, then print a sequence (one "." for each correct guess, one "o" for each incorrect guess).

```
#import "Gameplay.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {
    Gameplay * gp = [[Gameplay alloc] init];

}
return 0;
}


 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 @interface Gameplay : NSObject
 -(NSMutableArray *) board;

 @end


@implementation Gameplay
- (id)init {
self = [super init];
if (self)
{
    [self board];
}
return self;
}
-(NSMutableArray *) board{
NSMutableArray *colors = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"r",@"b",@"y",@"g",@"o",@"p", nil];

NSMutableArray *choose = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    int randomize = arc4random()%[colors count];
    NSString *turn = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[colors objectAtIndex: randomize]];
    [choose addObject: turn];
    [colors removeObjectAtIndex: randomize];
}
NSFileHandle(

for(int i = 0;i < 4;i++){
    NSLog(@"%@",[choose objectAtIndex:i]);
}
return choose;
}
@end



#import "Gameplay.h"
int main(int argc,
@autoreleasepool {
    Gameplay * gp = [[Gameplay alloc] init];

}
return 0;
}


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Gameplay : NSObject
-(NSMutableArray *) board;

@end


 @implementation Gameplay
 - (id)init {
self = [super init];
if (self)
{
    [self board];
}
return self;
}
-(NSMutableArray *) board{
NSMutableArray *colors = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"r",@"b",@"y",@"g",@"o",@"p", nil];

NSMutableArray *choose = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    int randomize = arc4random()%[colors count];
    NSString *turn = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[colors objectAtIndex: randomize]];
    [choose addObject: turn];
    [colors removeObjectAtIndex: randomize];
}
NSFileHandle(

for(int i = 0;i < 4;i++){
    NSLog(@"%@",[choose objectAtIndex:i]);
}
return choose;
}
@end
```

Comment: First, parse your posted code down to only what's relevant to the question your asking.  Second, what have you tried so far, and what are you struggling with?

Comment: Please fix your indentation and other problems with the code you've posted so it will actually compile. Can you be more specific about what you do and don't understand, and what's tripping you up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing strings to keyboard input in ObjC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19171120)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did not get your question exactly what you want to achieve. But i would like you to recommend that for randomly arranging your mutable array try like this below, Whenever you execute the code, Your order of mutable array will be changed randomly so on the basis of that you can fetch the value and write the checker accordingly on the basis of user input.:--

```
NSMutableArray *mutArr=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"red",@"green",@"blue",@"white",nil];
int i=0;
for (i=0; i<[mutArr count]; i++)
{
NSUInteger rand= (arc4random() %[mutArr count]);
    [mutArr exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:rand];
    NSLog(@"%@",mutArr);
}
```